# dplyr: Iterative calculation

Tags: r, vector, iteration, dplyr

I'm trying to figure out if there's a way for dplyr to calculate a variable row-by-row, such that it can reference the results calculated one record prior.

Here is code that achieves what I want using for-loops:

```
x <- data.frame(x1 = c(1:10)) 

#This works.
x$x2[1] <- 0

for (i in 2:nrow(x)) {
  x$x2[i] <- x$x2[i-1]*1.1 + 1
}
```

My naive dplyr attempt, which doesn't work:

```
#This doesn't work. "Error: object'x1' not found"
x %>% mutate(x2 = ifelse(x1 == 1, 0, lag(x2)*1.1 + 1))
```

It would be nice to find a dplyr solution since this step is part of a workflow that heavily relies on it.

Thank you.

---

**Edit:**

The above is a simplified example of what I'm trying to do. A closed form solution will not work because the function applied is more complex and dynamic than what is shown here. For example, suppose that 'add_var' and 'pwr_var' are random integers, and I want to calculate this:

```
x$x2[1] <- 0

for (i in 2:nrow(x)) {
  x$x2[i] <- ( x$x2[i-1]*1.1 + x$add_var[i] ) ^ x$pwr_var[i]
}
```

Comment: Is this just a toy example you come up with?

Comment: What version of `dplyr` are you using that gave you the "object 'x1' not found" error?

Comment: According to     sessionInfo(), I'm using     dplyr_0.5.0

Answer (score 4):

In general, if you want to calculate values that rely on previous values, you are better off using `Reduce`. here's an example with your data

```
x %>% mutate(x3 = Reduce(function(a,b) a*1.1+1, 1:(n()-1), 0, acc=T))
```

But in your example, there is a [closed form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function#Examples) for the term that doesn't rely on iteration. You can do

```
x %>% mutate(x4=(1.1^(row_number()-1)-1)/(1.1-1)*1)
```

Comment: This is a better solution.  I forgot about reduce.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use the expanded notation, then you can use the library magrittr, define a function that performs your transformation, and then apply the pipe operators.  Also, use the data_frame object, not the data.frame object for dplyr.

```
    library(dplyr)
    library(magrittr)
    x <- data_frame(x1 = c(1:10))
    f_x <- function(x){(x-1)*1.1+1}
    x$x2 <-x %$% x1 %>% f_x
```

Answer (score -3):

Your code works for me. Here is the result:

```
   x1        x2
1   1  0.000000
2   2  1.000000
3   3  2.100000
4   4  3.310000
5   5  4.641000
6   6  6.105100
7   7  7.715610
8   8  9.487171
9   9 11.435888
10 10 13.579477
```

Can you try dplyr code line as:

```
 x %>% mutate(x2 = ifelse(x1 == 1, 0, lag(x2)*1.1 + 1))
```

Comment: I do not get that result on my machine when I run the `dplyr` code.

Comment: @MrFlick the `for` loop portion worked, the `dplyr` portion did not, which I think was OP's point